# White space issue for the Pre element

Tags: html, css

I am facing a really annoying issue with the HTML `pre` element. I have no idea why it's creating so much white spaces when I never actually did that. Inside my code editor, everything is properly indented, made sure that the HTML is 100% valid but whenever I test on my browser; the white spaces suddenly appear. To make things more understandable, here's an image of how the `pre` looks inside my console.

[image]

And here's the HTML / CSS code.

**HTML**

```
<pre>
    &#60;!DOCTYPE html&#62;
    &#60;html&#62;
    &#60;head&#62;
    &#60;title&#62;My website&#60;title&#62;
    &#60;/head&#62;
    &#60;body&#62;

    &#60;script type="text/javascript"&#62;
         alert("Hello world!");
    &#60;/script&#62;
    &#60;/body&#62;
    &#60;/html&#62;
</pre>
```

**CSS**

```
pre{
    overflow: auto;
    background: #ddd;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
    white-space: -ms-pre-wrap;
}
```

If it helps, I am also using ratchet in order to make it mobile ready.
(Please note that removing the white-space did not help).
Regards.

Comment: HTML ignores tabs.   I think the `pre` element respects them.  Are you _sure_ you removed all the white space?

Comment: Hmm, well that actually fixed it. But that will most definitely make the HTML hard to read for later edits. Isn't there a way around that?

Comment: `pre` *pre*serves white-space.  What is your reasoning for using it here?

Comment: @fauxserious - I was just about to ask the same question, if you aren't using `pre` to preserve whitespace, then why are you using it at all?

Comment: @RayJoe - I've run into that same problem, to make the output nice, the formatted code is ugly.   I couldn't find away around it.   Sometimes, you just have to move on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of:

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

Use:

```
white-space: pre-line
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pw8adv1c/)

> [**white-space**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)
>
> The `white-space` property is used to describe how whitespace inside the
>   element is handled.
>
> ***pre-wrap***
>
> Sequences of whitespace are preserved.
>
> ***pre-line***
>
> Sequences of whitespace are collapsed.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: Note that you don't need the `<pre>` element for this, as you can apply `white-space: pre-line;` to any selector

Comment: @xec Thanks for the tip! :D Now, if only the CSS naming made even a tiny bit of intuitive sense . . . I mean, when whitespace is pre-wrap it is preserved but when it is pre-line it is collapsed. No way this makes sense when you first hear it, and you just have to end up memorizing it.